# How do I run NPM from FAKE?

Tags: npm, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

**Important:**

Since this is something I figured many people would like to do I added a helper to FAKE to do it: http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-npmhelper.html

**Question start here:**

I'm trying to run NPM from Fake, but for some reason it won't work.

My fake target look like this:

```
Target "Web" (fun _ ->
  let result =
          ExecProcess (fun info ->
              info.FileName <- "npm.cmd"
              info.Arguments <- "install ./src/FAKESimple.Web/"
              info.WorkingDirectory <- "."
          ) (System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes 1.0)
  if result <> 0 then failwith "Operation failed or timed out"
  trace "Hello World from FAKE"
)
```

The error message I get is:

```
module.js:338                                                                 
    throw err;                                                                
          ^                                                                   
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\dev\git\FAKESimpleDemo\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-
cli.js'                                                                       
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)                    
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)                               
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)                             
    at startup (node.js:129:16)                                               
    at node.js:814:3                                                          
Running build failed.                                                         
Error:                                                                        
System.Exception: Operation failed or timed out                               
   at FSI_0001.clo@62-10.Invoke(Unit _arg2) in C:\Dev\git\FAKESimpleDemo\build
.fsx:line 69                                                                  
   at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 483
```

The default `npm.cmd` look like this:

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" "%~dp0\.\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
) ELSE (
  node "%~dp0\.\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
)
```

So it seems that `%~dp0` get resolved to whatever is the working directory of the `ExecProcess` and not the path of the folder to `npm.cmd` which is intended.

Any idea of how to resolve this or how npm should be run from FAKE?

**Update**

I have a sample project that illustrates it here: https://github.com/mastoj/FAKESimpleDemo/commit/1066c6d78cd0c8d8ab261f647118b30d15487c2f

It requires that node is installed.

**Update 2:**

I think I now what is going on, but not how to solve it. If you run `npm` from a regular command line everything works as it should, but if you run `"npm"` (note the quotes) you get the same error. For some reason `%~dp0` get resolved differently depending on how something is invoked, which find strange.

Comment: Did you try running npm directly from fake, so info.FileName <- "npm" etc..?

Comment: @halcwb, I don't remember but I think so :). Everything is solved now and I also made it easier for other to do the same thing with the node helpers for fake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FAKE and PAKET to build an Angular 6 app and pack it in a NuGet package. The targets that builds my app is the following:

```
Target.create "BuildAngular"( fun _ -> 
    Trace.setBuildNumber (CreateInformationalVersion versionInfo)
    Npm.run "buildproductive" (fun o -> { o with WorkingDirectory = "./src"})
    Directory.Move("./src/dist/", dirAngularOutput)
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory (dirAngularOutput, dirBuildOutput @@ "gui.zip")
)
```

The parameter "buildproductive" is a target I defined in package.json in the scripts array:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "buildproductive": "node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:ci": "node_modules/.bin/ng test --karma-config=src/karma.ci.conf.js",
    "test:headless": "node_modules/.bin/ng test --karma-config=src/karma.headless.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```